# EXEC spawning gunicorn: No such file or directory when deploy a Django project

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, deployment, gunicorn

I try to deploy a `django` project with `nginx` and `gunicorn`. But when I start `gunicorn` I get error

> gunicorn.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning
>   /home/project/projectenv/bin/gunicorn: No such file or directory

**/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/project/project/
ExecStart=/home/project/projectenv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --error-logfile error.log --workers 2 --bind unix:/home/project/project.sock project.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`ls /home/project/projectenv/bin/gunicorn` - it's ok.

Structure of the project

```
home
  oddsportal
    oddsportalenv
      bin
      ...
    oddsportal
      app
        ...
      oddsportal
        settings
        wsgi
        ...
      manage.py
      ...
```

Comment: well, we know it’s not a permission issue if it’s root (which may not be a great idea, in prod btw).  but i would check all other files or directories referenced in that config for existence.  it might just be giving you the command that failed, rather than the missing file name.

Comment: Run ``which gunicorn``. Is the result the same to ``ExecStart``?